# How to choose my Cassandra key for correct default sorting?

Tags: cassandra, cql

My table `samples` consists of columns like this:

```
id : uuid
created : timestamp
device : ascii
reading : float
```

Most of my queries will be to fetch the most recent `n` samples across all devices, so I would like this to be the default sorting:

```sql
SELECT * FROM samples LIMIT 1024
```

I would also like to be able to efficiently fetch the most recent `n` samples for a given *device*:

```sql
SELECT * FROM samples WHERE device = 'abc' LIMIT 1024
```

How should I design my partition key to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cassandra, it is recommended to take a query-based modeling approach.  To this end, it is not uncommon to have one table for each query which needs to be supported.

```
SELECT * FROM samples LIMIT 1024
```

For this first query the biggest problem I see right away, is that there is no `WHERE` clause.  This will cause Cassandra to have to check every node to build a result set; definitely don't want that happening.  But it sounds like you care most about recent data, or data by a specific date.  To do that, we'll need to create a partition key or "bucket" based on a date/time component.

**Note, this is also required because data retrieved from multiple partitions cannot be sorted.**

For this, the cardinality of your data is important.  You're selecting the top 1024, so is it common to get that many in a single day?  Or is that over a week?  For now, I'll assume "day," and add a `day_bucket` column.

```
CREATE TABLE samples_by_day (
  id uuid,
  created timestamp,
  device ascii,
  reading float,
  day_bucket bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (day_bucket,created,id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC, id ASC);
```

This primary key definition will partition data by day (ex: 20200710).  Within those partitions, data will be ordered by `created` in descending order (to get the most-recent on top).  The `id` column is added to ensure uniqueness.  This will support the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM samples_by_day
WHERE day_bucket = 20200710 LIMIT 1024;
```

For multiple days, you could run multiple queries.  You could even "bucket" by week or month, assuming that doesn't push the bounds of the 2 billion cells/partition limit.

Supporting this query:

```
SELECT * FROM samples
WHERE device = 'abc' LIMIT 1024;
```

...is *much* easier.

```
CREATE TABLE samples_by_device (
  id uuid,
  created timestamp,
  device ascii,
  reading float,
  day_bucket bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (device,created,id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC, id ASC);
```

This works, but will likely run into the problem of "unbound row growth."  Basically, if device samples keep being added for each device, the partition size will eventually max-out.  So adding `day_bucket` (or whatever time bucket works for you) as an additional partition key is probably necessary:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((device,day_bucket),created,id)
```

With this change, the query also needs to change:

```
SELECT * FROM samples_by_device
WHERE device = 'abc' AND day_bucket = 20200710 LIMIT 1024;
```

Comment: How does this work if I want the most recent `n` samples but I don't know how many days that is? Do I need to implement this logic application-side and just keep asking for more days until I have enough?

Comment: @sdgfsdh I would say that you could definitely abstract it in your application level to make it _look_ like it's one call, but make separate calls in your data access layer (for each day) to Cassandra.